# XHTML Mobile 1.2 - W3C Validation Invalid because of Target _blank

Tags: html, mobile, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm having a target that goes offsite on my mobile website (address of location goes to a google maps of it) so I target _blank the link so users don't lose the site while doing this.

But it seems target="_blank" is invalid for the W3C...

> Line 56, Column 288: there is no attribute "target"
>   …0.018282&z=16&iwloc=A" target="_blank" class="adress">Adress…
>
> You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error message for further information.
>
> How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute, (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this attribute. If you received this error when using the  element to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid flash.

I'm in XHTML Mobile 1.2, because that's a mobile Website (so I pretty much can't change from that). Is there a valid way to put in that property in XHTML Mobile 1.2?

Already tried to switch to XHTML Transitional, but I'm losing a couple of functionalities of the website doing that. So it's pretty much ot of the question.

Comment: What functionality do you lose by going to Transitional?

Comment: With transitionnal, I get the whole page in a mobile Iphone browser. With Mobile, it's already zommed in on the content

Comment: You might be able to get the zooming taken care of with a meta viewport tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XHTML Strict et al., target is not a valid attribute.  Instead of `target="_blank"` you are supposed to use `rel="external"`.  I have no idea how widely supported that is on mobile browsers, but if you're supposed to adhere to the Mobile Profile 1.x standard, that's what you're supposed to do.  You may need to use JavaScript to get the desired behavior in this case.

Comment: Yes, that makes my code valid, but I lose the behavior to open the link in a new tab. Maybe I will have to do it with Javascript.

Comment: Yes, if you want valid code under that DTD *and* the new-window-opening behavior, I believe you will have to resort to JavaScript.